# Implementing Syncfusion schedule in server running project (Typescript)

Tags: php, typescript, server, syncfusion

I am a Junior web developer, currently new to javascript, typescript and php. I'm using syncfusion schedule library to make a drag and drop calendar in typescript. I successfully was able to create the calendar but now I don't know how to implemented to the project. All files are .php and syncfusions scheduler is in .html. Tried to changed it to php but then the calendar would not load. Has anyone implemented successfully this library to a project? What tips can you give me?

Answer (score 0):

Response from Syncfusion Support

### Original

We could render our syncfusion Scheduler component in PHP, and we have created a simple sample based on your requirements.

Schedule Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PHPSchedule-1642979968

Please refer to below KB for more information:

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10280/how-to-use-ej2-controls-in-php

### Update

Please try with below sample in which we have rendered the default scheduler with appointments.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/schedule1060361176

Output:
[image]

Currently, we have not provided PHP support for the latest version of our EJ2 controls. We have already considered this as a feature from our end. This feature will be included in any one of our upcoming releases. Generally, we will plan features based on customer interest, feature rank and wishlist plan.

Refer to the below link to know about the feature status.
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/5178/php-wrapper-support-in-ej2